# Running scrapy with PyCharm - Debug works but Run does not work

Tags: python, scrapy, pycharm, python-3.6

I met a very strange issue, running Scrapy with PyCharm:
 
With the exact same configuration, Debug works, but Run with PyCharm does NOT work.

- Windows 10
- PyCharm 2016.3.3
- Scrapy  1.3.3
- Python  3.6.0

Configuration:
[PyCharm Edit Configuration Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRghc.png)

When I attempt to debug scrapy, it works perfectly.
When I attempt to run scrapy, I get below error:

```
C:\Users\baib2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe 
C:/Users/baib2/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Lib/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py crawl scenelist_spider
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/baib2/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Lib/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 8, in <module   
    import scrapy
  File "C:\Users\baib2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\__init__.py", line 27, in <module   
    from . import _monkeypatches
  File "C:\Users\baib2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\_monkeypatches.py", line 20, in <module   
    import twisted.persisted.styles  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\baib2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\persisted\styles.py", line 21, in <module   
    from twisted.python.compat import _PY3, _PYPY
  File "C:\Users\baib2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\__init__.py", line 11, in <module   
    from .compat import unicode
  File "C:\Users\baib2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\compat.py", line 612, in <module   
    from http import cookiejar as cookielib
  File "C:\Users\baib2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\__init__.py", line 8, in <module   
    from scrapy.http.headers import Headers
  File "C:\Users\baib2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\__init__.py", line 10, in <module   
    from scrapy.http.request import Request
  File "C:\Users\baib2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 8, in <module   
    from w3lib.url import safe_url_string
  File "C:\Users\baib2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\w3lib\url.py", line 17, in <module   
    from six.moves.urllib.request import pathname2url, url2pathname
  File "C:\Users\baib2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 92, in __get__
    result = self._resolve()
  File "C:\Users\baib2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 160, in _resolve
    module = _import_module(self.mod)
  File "C:\Users\baib2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\baib2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 88, in <module   
    import http.client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'http.client'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

No need to attach any code because even running the command:

`python3.exe C:\Users\baib2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py`

will produce the same error.

I've checked my **sys.path**, comparing with run, debug has 1 more path:

'C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.3.3\helpers\pydev'

And I really don't think this shall make any difference.

Hope someone can take a look, thanks!

Comment: `No module named 'http.client'` means you are running something that is meant for python3 on python2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I'm 100% sure I'm using python3. You can see I'm using Python3 Interpreter in my attachment.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this in the end ? I'm facing EXACTLY same symptoms - scrapy runs fine in debug, but fails on http.client when in normal run or from command line.

Comment: I didn't figured out the reason. I tried to enable "Show Command line afterwords", it worked.

Comment: I had the same exact issue and surprisingly the solution worked. I still don't understand how it fixed it.

Comment: For me checking "Run with Python console" worked. I don't have Show Command line afterwards in my version of Pycharm (2018.3.5)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Menu  Run>Edit configurations
enable checkbox "Show Command line afterwards"
This helps for me

Comment: Is there an explanation why this is the case? I just ran into the issue and it was resolved in the same way, but I still would like to know why it happens.

Answer (score 5):

In case you are using a new version of PyCharm where `Show Command line afterward` is not available anymore, `Run with Python console` solves the issue.

Comment: This ends up in PyCharm to stuck on the task "Connecting to console...". It never finishes therefore the actual Python program is never started.

Answer (score 0):

I've also spent some time tracking a similar problem.

My issue was that I have a local module named `http` which of course does not submodule called `client`. Another similar issue is described [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000000884-pycharm-cannot-debug-with-ModuleNotFound-error).

The solution is to change *Working directory* for this test invocation via *Edit configurations*.